# I can call parent function in iframe, but cannot change parent variable

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an `inside.html` which is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <button id="mybutton">Click</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            parent.changeName("init");
        });

        $("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
            parent.changeName("changed");
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

It is loaded by an `iframe` from `outside.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>  
    <body>
        <iframe src="inside.html" style="overflow: scroll; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;">
        </iframe>
    </body>
    <script>
        var name = "";
        function changeName(arg) {
            name = arg;
            alert(arg);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Now, when I load the page or click the button of `inside.html`, the `changeName` function in `outside.html` is called, as alertbox is shown. However, variable `name` is not changed (I cheched from the console). I don't know why.

Both file are in the same domain, so there is no cross-domain problem.

You can view the live page if you don't mind:

[outside.html on my server](http://www.lindenbaum.net.au/testfile/outside.html)

Thank you!

Comment: I don't seem to have the problem on your page. In what browser are you testing?

Comment: type: name , in your console, it shows "changed". It appears fine.

Comment: @Carbosound1 I am using Chrome. When I use inspect and check the value of `name`, it's empty.

Comment: @jamesemanon Why? I use Chrome and in html inspect, type name, show empty string.

Comment: @jamesemanon Now it really puzzles me, in ie's console, the varaible `name` is changed, but in Chrome's console, it is not. Is this problem browser dependent? Does the variable changed or not?

Comment: Could it be that in Chrome you are trying to look for name in the iframe and not in the parent?

Comment: When you have the console open with Elements inspector, make sure you're highlighting an element in the outside.html when you print the variable.
If you're highlighting an element in inside.html then it'll print empty string.

Comment: @DavidMårtensson Thank you. My fault not to click the outside html. But for inside.html, there should be no variable `name` at all. Why not an `ReferenceError`